# prevent seekbar click in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-seek

I am using a seekbar. and I want to control it only by moving the thumb.

How can I disable the click on the progressdrawable?

I tried `android:clickable="false"` but it didn't work.

my seek Bar code in XML

```
      <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/myseek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_left"
        android:thumb="@drawable/left_unlocker_bkg" >
    </SeekBar>
```

My Seekbar  code  for  onSeekChangedListner

```
unlockSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        toastText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        if (seekBar.getProgress() < 10) {
                            seekBar.setProgress(0);
                        }
                        toastText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        toastText.setText("Slide to Unclock");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                            int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                        if (progress == 100) {
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            v.vibrate(100);
                            finish();
                        } 
                    }
                });
```

Currently, the user can click on the progress and the thumb moves I want to DISABLE it . Please help

Comment: have you got the solution

Answer (score 6):

You can use **android:enabled="false"** , but it will display disable effect [darken your seekbar].

So if you want to display enable seekbar with no response to thumb activity, implement touch event handler with return true as shown below.

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
 }
});
```

Comment: This disabled the thumb as well which is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle touch event of the seekbar. I think below link will be helpful to you.

[Android seekbar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787906/android-seekbar-solution)